# Not able to get the CSS progress bar with white and grey

Tags: css, progress-bar

I am trying to make a progress bar which is my requirement like the following image:

[image]

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bar {
box-sizing: content-box;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 20px 50px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}
.bar span {
display: block;
height: 100%;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 26%);
position: relative;
}
.bar span:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-size: 50px 50px;
background-image: linear-gradient(
-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent );
animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
0% { background-position: 0 0; }
100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bar animate"><span style="width: 100%"></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I get this through my code:

[image]

Can anyone help me getting the exact progress bar or similar as shown in the expected like where am I going wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not saying this is the only way of fixing this. But you could just go ahead and invert the colors you have.

```
background-image: linear-gradient( 
    -45deg, 
    rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 25%, 
    transparent 25%, 
    transparent 50%, 
    rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 50%, 
    rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 75%, 
    transparent 75%, 
    transparent );
```

And invert the colors for this one as well:

```
background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 26%);
```

```css
.bar {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 20px 50px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.bar span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 26%);
    position: relative;
}
.bar span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
background-image: linear-gradient( 
    -45deg, 
    rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 25%, 
    transparent 25%, 
    transparent 50%, 
    rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 50%, 
    rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 75%, 
    transparent 75%, 
    transparent );
    animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
    0% {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 50px 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bar animate">
        <span style="width: 100%"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Happy to help @SaAshTechs

Answer (score 0):

You need a background with repeating-linear-gradient

```css
.background-lines {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, grey, 
  grey 5px, white 5px, white 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-lines">
text if needed
</div>
```

Comment: I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You added your colors the wrong way.
At first the background-color from `.bar span` gets applied, resulting in a gray background for the whole bar.
And at second the gradient from `.bar span:after` get's appliced since it comes `AFTER` the actual html element.

Therefore just swap your colors and you are good to go.
So the white/transparent color on your span and the gray color on your :after.

Like so:

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.bar {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.bar span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  position: relative;
}

.bar span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
  -45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .26) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .26) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .26) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent );
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar animate"><span style="width: 100%"></span></div>
```

Also keep in mind, as soon as you change the background color for the outer container for your bar (eg. body tag), the bar wil result in another color as well, since you are using transparent colors.